# ¿Cómo resuelvo operaciones básicas con datos al estilo SQL?

Tags: r

Hay una serie de operaciones elementales en **SQL** que me gustaría ver como resolverlas en **R**. En el caso del primero tenemos un `resulset` y en el segundo un [`data.frame`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html) ambas estructuras de datos son similares en muchos aspectos y me gustaría saber como resolver lo siguiente:

- Selección de columnas
- Filtros `WHERE`
- `INNER JOIN`
- `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`
- `CROSS JOIN`

Puede ser mediante el paquete base o con alguna librería específica. Para ejemplo, partir de los siguientes [`data.farme`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html):

```
clientes = data.frame(ClienteId = c(1:4), 
                    RazonSocial = c("Cliente 1", "Cliente 2", "Cliente 3", "Cliente 4"),
                    Direccion = c("Dirección 1", "Dirección 2", "Dirección 3", "Dirección 4"))

ventas = data.frame(ClienteId = c(1, 2, 3, 5), 
                    Monto = c(110, 50, 60, 90))
```

Es decir:

```
> clientes
  ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion
1         1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1
2         2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2
3         3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3
4         4   Cliente 4 Dirección 4

> ventas
  ClienteId Monto
1         1   110
2         2    50
3         3    60
4         5    90
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Propongo la solución alternativa usando las funciones del paquete `dplyr`

```r
clientes = data.frame(ClienteId = c(1:4), RazonSocial = c("Cliente 1", "Cliente 2", 
  "Cliente 3", "Cliente 4"), Direccion = c("Direccion 1", "Direccion 2", "Direccion 3", 
  "Direccion 4"))

ventas = data.frame(ClienteId = c(1, 2, 3, 5), Monto = c(110, 50, 60, 90))


library(dplyr)
```

## Seleccion de columnas

Se hace con la funcion `select`.

```r
select(clientes, Direccion, ClienteId)
#>     Direccion ClienteId
#> 1 Direccion 1         1
#> 2 Direccion 2         2
#> 3 Direccion 3         3
#> 4 Direccion 4         4
```

Con Ã­ndices

```r
select(clientes, 2:1)
#>   RazonSocial ClienteId
#> 1   Cliente 1         1
#> 2   Cliente 2         2
#> 3   Cliente 3         3
#> 4   Cliente 4         4
```

Puede remover si necesitas

```r
select(clientes, -1)
#>   RazonSocial   Direccion
#> 1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1
#> 2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2
#> 3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3
#> 4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4
select(clientes, -ClienteId)
#>   RazonSocial   Direccion
#> 1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1
#> 2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2
#> 3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3
#> 4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4
```

Interesante es usar el auxiliar `everithing()` para por ejemplo traer
una columna hacia el primer lugar

```r
select(clientes, RazonSocial, everything())
#>   RazonSocial ClienteId   Direccion
#> 1   Cliente 1         1 Direccion 1
#> 2   Cliente 2         2 Direccion 2
#> 3   Cliente 3         3 Direccion 3
#> 4   Cliente 4         4 Direccion 4
```

Otro *helpers* muy Ãºtil son los `starts_with`, `ends_with`, `contains`,
entre otros mas: que reciben una expresion regular o patron:

```r
select(clientes, contains("e"))  # todas las columnas que contienen 'e'
#>   ClienteId   Direccion
#> 1         1 Direccion 1
#> 2         2 Direccion 2
#> 3         3 Direccion 3
#> 4         4 Direccion 4
```

## Filtros

Notar que **no** tienes que repetir el nombre de la tabla
(`clientes[clientes$Direccion`) lo que hace el codigo mas facil de
escribir, entender, mantener.

```r
filter(clientes, Direccion == "Direccion 2")
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion
#> 1         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2
filter(clientes, Direccion != "Direccion 2")
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1
#> 2         3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3
#> 3         4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4
filter(clientes, Direccion %in% c("Direccion 1", "Direccion 2"))
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2
filter(clientes, Direccion %in% c("Direccion 1", "Direccion 2"))
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2
```

Me he hecho muy fan del tidyverse, sobre todo por que me es mas fácil
enseñarlo a quienes no han programado mucho antes. Por ejemplo `grep`
puede ser mas fácil de olvidar que hace a diferencia de `str_detect`
(detectar en string).

```r
library(stringr)
filter(clientes, str_detect(Direccion, "Dire.*[12]"))
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2
```

### Joins

```r
# por defecto busca la interseccion en nombres
inner_join(clientes, ventas)
#> Joining, by = "ClienteId"
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1   110
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2    50
#> 3         3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3    60
inner_join(clientes, ventas, by = "ClienteId")
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1   110
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2    50
#> 3         3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3    60

left_join(clientes, ventas)
#> Joining, by = "ClienteId"
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1   110
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2    50
#> 3         3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3    60
#> 4         4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4    NA

right_join(clientes, ventas)
#> Joining, by = "ClienteId"
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1   110
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2    50
#> 3         3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3    60
#> 4         5        <NA>        <NA>    90

full_join(clientes, ventas)
#> Joining, by = "ClienteId"
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1   110
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2    50
#> 3         3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3    60
#> 4         4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4    NA
#> 5         5        <NA>        <NA>    90
merge(x = clientes, y = ventas, by = "ClienteId", all = TRUE)
#>   ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
#> 1         1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1   110
#> 2         2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2    50
#> 3         3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3    60
#> 4         4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4    NA
#> 5         5        <NA>        <NA>    90
```

No existe forma directa:

```r
inner_join(mutate(clientes, k = 1), mutate(ventas, k = 1), by = "k")
#>    ClienteId.x RazonSocial   Direccion k ClienteId.y Monto
#> 1            1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1 1           1   110
#> 2            1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1 1           2    50
#> 3            1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1 1           3    60
#> 4            1   Cliente 1 Direccion 1 1           5    90
#> 5            2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2 1           1   110
#> 6            2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2 1           2    50
#> 7            2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2 1           3    60
#> 8            2   Cliente 2 Direccion 2 1           5    90
#> 9            3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3 1           1   110
#> 10           3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3 1           2    50
#> 11           3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3 1           3    60
#> 12           3   Cliente 3 Direccion 3 1           5    90
#> 13           4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4 1           1   110
#> 14           4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4 1           2    50
#> 15           4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4 1           3    60
#> 16           4   Cliente 4 Direccion 4 1           5    90
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta propuesta esta basada en el uso del paquete base de **R**, seguramente hay opciones mejores, pero vamos a ver que tampoco es muy complejo resolverlo así:

#### Selección de columnas

Muy sencillo, hay que definir las columnas a mostrar construyendo un [`vector`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/vector.html) de cualquiera de las formas posibles, pudiendo asimismo modificar el orden.

```
clientes[,c(2,1)]                        # Col 2 y 1
clientes[,2:1]                           # Col 2 y 1
clientes[,-1]                            # Todas menos la 1
clientes[,c("ClienteId", "RazonSocial")] # por nombre
```

#### Filtro de registros (`WHERE`)

Los filtros más comunes se mapean fácilmente y son combinables con operadores lógicos `&& (and)`, `|| (or)`, `! (not)`

```
clientes[clientes$Direccion == "Dirección 2",]                        # =
clientes[clientes$Direccion != "Dirección 2",]                        # <>
clientes[clientes$Direccion %in% c("Dirección 1", "Dirección 2"),]    # IN
clientes[!(clientes$Direccion %in% c("Dirección 1", "Dirección 2")),] # NOT IN
clientes[grep("Dire.*[12]", clientes$Direccion),]                     # Like (regexp)
```

#### `INNER JOIN`

Usando [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) podemos resolver cualquier tipo de `JOIN

```
> merge(x = clientes, y = ventas, by = "ClienteId")

  ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
1         1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1   110
2         2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2    50
3         3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3    60
```

#### `LEFT JOIN`

```
> merge(x = clientes, y = ventas, by = "ClienteId", all.x = TRUE)

  ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto
1         1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1   110
2         2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2    50
3         3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3    60
4         4   Cliente 4 Dirección 4    NA
```

#### `RIGHT JOIN`

```
> merge(x = clientes, y = ventas, by = "ClienteId", all.y = TRUE)

  ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto

1         1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1   110
2         2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2    50
3         3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3    60
4         5        <NA>        <NA>    90
```

#### `FULL JOIN`

```
> merge(x = clientes, y = ventas, by = "ClienteId", all = TRUE)

  ClienteId RazonSocial   Direccion Monto

1         1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1   110
2         2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2    50
3         3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3    60
4         4   Cliente 4 Dirección 4    NA
5         5        <NA>        <NA>    90
```

#### `CROSS JOIN`

```
> merge(x = clientes, y = ventas, by = NULL)

   ClienteId.x RazonSocial   Direccion ClienteId.y Monto
1            1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1           1   110
2            2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2           1   110
3            3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3           1   110
4            4   Cliente 4 Dirección 4           1   110
5            1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1           2    50
6            2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2           2    50
7            3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3           2    50
8            4   Cliente 4 Dirección 4           2    50
9            1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1           3    60
10           2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2           3    60
11           3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3           3    60
12           4   Cliente 4 Dirección 4           3    60
13           1   Cliente 1 Dirección 1           5    90
14           2   Cliente 2 Dirección 2           5    90
15           3   Cliente 3 Dirección 3           5    90
16           4   Cliente 4 Dirección 4           5    90
```