# ¿Cómo unir dos dataframes con distintas fechas?

Tags: r

Tengo datos de una serie temporal que no le faltan días:

```
2010-07-22 1199.50
2010-07-23 1190.50
2010-07-26 1183.50
2010-07-27 1168.00
```

en este ejemplo los días que faltan son el 24 y 25, quiero comparar este `dataframe` con otro que tiene todos los días. Me gustaría crear uno nuevo que tenga tres columnas: Una con la fecha, otra con los valores de x y la otra con los valores de y. En el caso de los valores de x como no tienen todas las fechas quedaría con Nas.

Otra opción que también me vale sería crear las fechas que faltan y luego fácilmente con `rbind` puedo compararlo.

Cuando intento hacer rbind no me deja porque no tienen la misma cantidad de filas, con merge me sale algo muy raro, he probado haciendo un bucle, pero no lo consigo. Me podría indicar alguien como lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente pareciera ser que lo que buscas es lo que se conoce en SQL como `LEFT JOIN`, es decir todas las filas de un `df1` junto con las que coincidan de un `df2`. Esto se puede resolver con R base mediante `merge()`. Primero armamos un ejemplo similar a lo que comentas:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date('2010/07/22'), as.Date('2010/07/31'), by="day"),
    x =  runif(10)
)
#Eliminamos algunas filas para el df2
df2 <- df1[!(df1$date %in% as.Date(c('2010-07-24', '2010-07-25'))),]
```

y ahora, juntamos ambos `data.frame` mediante `merge()` usando como clave la columnas `date`:

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "date", all.x = TRUE)

         date         x.x         x.y
1  2010-07-22 0.310362963 0.310362963
2  2010-07-23 0.009058759 0.009058759
3  2010-07-24 0.312455305          NA
4  2010-07-25 0.588714035          NA
5  2010-07-26 0.341069143 0.341069143
6  2010-07-27 0.275959616 0.275959616
7  2010-07-28 0.779029812 0.779029812
8  2010-07-29 0.652961296 0.652961296
9  2010-07-30 0.127697322 0.127697322
10 2010-07-31 0.468899165 0.468899165
```

Para una más completa lista de las operaciones de combinación de datos que puedes usar en R te sugiero [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/como-resuelvo-en-r-operaciones-b%C3%A1sicas-de-sql)