# Buscar V en R código

Tags: r

tengo una consulta que código puedo utilizar para hacer un tipo de buscar V en R cuando no tengo registros únicos

Un ejempplo:
A partir de esta información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Traer la información de Tipo de la siguiente tabla, sin eliminar registros repetidos en la tabla principal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien te refieres a una consulta SQL? con u group by por tipo creo que resolverías tu problema.

Comment: No, tengo dos dataframe en R y quiero realizar en un dataframe del dato Tipo y que aparezca en el otro dataframe sin eliminar los registros duplicados

Comment: Lo que buscas es básicamente un `LEFT JOIN` entre dos `data.frames`,  las operaciones de combinación de datos están ampliamente explicadas aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/c%c3%b3mo-resuelvo-operaciones-b%c3%a1sicas-con-datos-al-estilo-sql, Revisalo, tienes documentadas opciones con R base y con `dplyr`, cualquier cosa nos comentas.

Comment: Patricio Moracho, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, porque eres muy oportuno, entiendes las preguntas y das unas excelentes respuestas