# ¿cómo sustitur valores que cumplan la condición de otro data frame?

Tags: r, rstudio, data, r-dplyr

Estoy trabajando con datos de la ENIGH 2018 y en una base de datos hay una variable llamada "entidad" conformada por 5 dígitos, los primeros dos correspondientes al estado y los restantes al municipio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otro data frame están los nombres que le corresponden a cada dato número.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sustituí el código con su nombre correspondiente usando la fórmula "BUSCARV" en excel pero quisiera saber como se hace en R studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la jerga de base de datos, esto se lo conoce como un `left join`, es decir las filas de una tabla principal, mas las coincidentes por una o más columnas, de otra secundaria. Considerando que tuvieras dos `data.frames` como estos:

```
read.table(text="ubica_geo Gasto
1001 98323225
1002 5856263.28
1003 1091044.08
1004 741336.48
1005 3511879.02
1006 748698.74", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE) -> df1


read.table(text="codigo mun
0 'No aplica No aplica'
1000 'Aguascalientes No identificado'
1001 'Aguascalientes Aguascalientes'
1002 'Aguascalientes Asientos'
1003 'Aguascalientes Calvillo'
1004 'Aguascalientes Cosío'
1005 'Aguascalientes Jesús María'
1006 'Aguascalientes Pabellón de Arteaga'
1007 'Aguascalientes Rincón de Romos'", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE) -> df2
```

Dónde la relación está dada por `ubica_geo` en uno y `codigo` en el otro, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

**1. Usar R base y la función `merge()`**:

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = "ubica_geo", by.y = "codigo", all.x = TRUE)
```

**2. Usar `dplyr/tidyverse` y el verbo `left_join()`**

```
library("tidyverse")

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("ubica_geo" = "codigo"))
```

En ambos caso la salida sería algo así:

```
  ubica_geo      Gasto                                mun
1      1001 98323225.0      Aguascalientes Aguascalientes
2      1002  5856263.3            Aguascalientes Asientos
3      1003  1091044.1            Aguascalientes Calvillo
4      1004   741336.5               Aguascalientes Cosío
5      1005  3511879.0         Aguascalientes Jesús María
6      1006   748698.7 Aguascalientes Pabellón de Arteaga
```

Para mayor información: [¿Cómo resuelvo operaciones básicas con datos al estilo SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/c%C3%B3mo-resuelvo-operaciones-b%C3%A1sicas-con-datos-al-estilo-sql)