# Unión de bases con left join en R

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de unir dos bases de datos con left join en R. Necesito que la base 1(SMFINAL)-que tiene como primera columna la variable interview_key- se una con la misma variable (interview_key) pero de la base 2 (HRFINAL)

¿cómo puedo hacerlo con left join?
muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo resuelvo operaciones básicas con datos al estilo SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/c%c3%b3mo-resuelvo-operaciones-b%c3%a1sicas-con-datos-al-estilo-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando la función left_join de la libreria dplyr

```
left_join(SMFINAL, HRFINAL, by = "interview_key")
```

En ambas bases la variable por la cual quieres hacer el match deben tener el mismo nombre y clase.

En este caso, la base madre es SMFINAL, es decir, la que va en el primer parámetro del left_join.