# Unir Dos Dataframes con columna en comun (ID) y traer en una sola dataframe columnas de anteriores

Tags: sql, r, rstudio

Les agradezco mucho de la orientación que me puedan dar, llevo mucho tiempo dando vueltas y no encuentro solución. Tengo dos dataframes:

```
 Dataframe 1 (occ_espe2)

 Dataframe 2 (occ_espe_name1)
```

Ahora, requiero unir al Dataframe 1 las columnas del Dataframe 2. Es decir, requiero crear un nuevo Dataframe que incluya todas las columnas de ambos, pero con la condicion de que se unan por la columna "ID"

He intentado esto, pero obtengo error

```
 join <- occ_espe2 [occ_espe_name$ID %in% occ_espe2$ID]
 join <- occ_espe2 %>% full_join[occ_espe_2$ID %in% occ_espe_name$ID, ]
 join <- occ_espe2[occ_espe_name$ID %in% occ_espe2$ID, ]
 join <- occ_espe2 %>% right_join(occ_espe_name, by ="ID")
 join <- occ_espe_name1 [occ_espe_name1$ID %in% occ_espe2$ID]
 occ_espe3 <- occ_espe2 ([occ_espe2$ID =="ID" & occ_espe_name$ID == "ID", ])
join <- occ_espe2 %>% full_join(occ_espe_name1, by ="ID")

Lo unico que me ha funcionado, sin modificar las filas es: join = merge (occ_espe2, 
occ_espe_name1, all.x=TRUE)
```

Pero no me esta trayendo la información organizada por ID

Por favor, ayuda

Comment: Bienvenida Clara Morales-Rozo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Sería bueno que compartieras un ejemplo de ambos `data.frame`  sino, estamos un poco a ciegas con respecto  a tu pregunta. Hay muchas formas de unir `data.frames` te sugiero que leas esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/c%c3%b3mo-resuelvo-operaciones-b%c3%a1sicas-con-datos-al-estilo-sql por otro lado, por lo que comentas, pareciera que en occ_espe_name1 podrías llegar a tener más de una fila por ID, es así?

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio!! Voy a hacer el recorrido que me indicas y mejorar mis preguntas. Ya logré solucionar con ayuda de Aldo. Mil gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

De partida, utilizar `join` como nombre puede traer problemas con algunas librerías que incluyen una función con el mismo nombre. Te recomiendo que modifiques ligeramente el nombre, como: `join`.

Además, no sabemos la diferencia entre `occ_espe_name` y `occ_espe_name1`. Quizás allí está el error.

La forma más simple de unir dos data frame con las funciones `*_join` de `dpylr` es:

```
library(dplyr)

occ_espe2 %>%
  left_join(y = occ_espe_name1, by = 'ID') -> join_
```

Si esto resulta en error, debes subir un extracto de tus datos para ver si es que el error está en los elementos de entra, ya que la función debiese resultar.

Otra cosa común que pasa al utilizar funciones de estas características es que hay varias librerías con el mismo nombre de función y diferentes argumentos. Si ese es el caso, hay que ser específico al llamar a una función:

```
occ_espe2 %>%
  dplyr::left_join(y = occ_espe_name1, by = 'ID') -> join_
```

---

Tal como indica Patricio, la segunda dataframe posee observaciones repetidas. 265 para ser específico:

```
library(tidyverse)

occ_esp <- read_csv('occ_espe3.csv')

occ_esp_name <- readxl::read_xlsx('occ_espe_name1.xlsx')

dim(occ_esp)
#[1] 6317   43
dim(occ_esp_name)
#[1] 7428   47

length(unique(occ_esp$ID)) == dim(occ_esp)[1]
#[1] TRUE

length(unique(occ_esp_name$ID)) == dim(occ_esp_name)[1]
#[1] FALSE

dim(occ_esp_name)[1] - length(unique(occ_esp_name$ID))
#[1] 265
```

Debes tomar una decisión para reducir el dataframe. Una opción es seleccionar la primera observación por ID (puede ser promedio, mediana, última, etc, va en como deseas tú reducir las observaciones):

```
occ_esp %>% 
  left_join(occ_esp_name, by = 'ID') %>% 
  dim()
#[1] 6578   89

occ_esp_name %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1) -> occ_esp_name_reducido

occ_esp %>% 
  left_join(occ_esp_name_reducido, by = 'ID') %>% 
  dim()
#[1] 6317   89
```

Comment: Al aplicar la función indicada, me esta "sumando" más filas de las que tengo en occ_espe2 (6317 obs. of 42 var). Lo que debo obtener, son las mismas filas de occ_espe2, a las cuales se le suman las columnas de occ_espe_name1 (7428 obs. 47 var) bajo un mismo punto en común que es el ID. Ya cambie el nombre como sugeriste,  y al aplicar la funcion que me diste me da 6578 obs. of 88 var. Mientras que cuando hago sub_occ = merge (occ_espe2, occ_espe_name1, all.x=TRUE), une manteniendo filas y de acuerdo con adicion columnas, pero sin parametro de unión que sería el ID. ¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Comment: Es muy extraño, `left_join` no debiera aumentar el número de filas, para eso está `full_join` o `right_join` si `y` presenta más observaciones. Si hicieras tu ejemplo reproducible podríamos encontrar el error

Comment: Me podrías indicar por favor, cómo puedo hacer mi ejemplo reproducible? es muy importante para mí resolver el error.

Comment: Puedes utilizar `dput(occ_espe2[1:100,])` y `dput(occ_espe_name1[1:100,])` o subir los archivos a drive o algún otro servicio de almacenamiento

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Te comparto una carpeta en Drive, donde estan los dos archivos. La idea es "unirlos" manteniendo las filas de occ_espe2, y que una con occ_espe_name1, con la condicion que compartan el mismo ID. Podrías orientarme? quizá estoy haciendo algo mal. El enlace es: https://livejaverianaedu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/personal/morales_clara_javeriana_edu_co/Documents/Avances%20Doctorado/Union_Listados?csf=1&web=1&e=7am9h5

Comment: Me aparece este mensaje: `We're sorry, but xxxx@hotmail.com can't be found in the livejaverianaedu-my.sharepoint.com directory. Please try again later, while we try to automatically fix this for you.`

Comment: Este te abre?: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TP4pZV1qbcp7Y8DiVxNy5dyi_U95yMEw?usp=sharing

Comment: @ClaraMorales-Rozo listo, lee la actualización de mi respuesta

Comment: Te agradezco no inmesanmente!!! Mil y mil gracias. Fue de mucha ayuda. :)