# Agregar columnas si cumple condición de nombre en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo dos datasets, con las siguientes caracteristicas:
Primer dataset:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segundo data set:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es agregar las columnas de Lat , Long de acuerdo a la denominacion de Country.Region. Es decir si es Afghanistan agregar Lat y Long_ segun corresponda.

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenida. Si tienes un código que hayas intentado agrégalo a la pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenida  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Lo que buscas es algo que en el ambito de las bases relacionales se conoce como `left join`. Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/c%c3%b3mo-resuelvo-operaciones-b%c3%a1sicas-con-datos-al-estilo-sql