# Merged data condicionado a fila especificas en R

Tags: r, datatables, dataframe, web-scrapping

Tengo el siguiente problema:

- Dataframe 1 : con datos de empresas de diversos países.
- Dataframe 2 : con datos económicos de países.

Quiero crear un Dataframe 3 donde aparezcan todos las columnas, pero con los datos económicos del país correspondiente a cada empresa. El país viene en la 3 columna del Dataframe 1 y en la 1 del Dataframe 2.

He probado

```
Pero no son iguales en tamaño, seria similar a la función "BUSCARV" en excel pero no encuentro su equivalente en R 

Muchas gracias
```

Comment: Bienvenido user a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta para que ésta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: En lineas generales lo que buscas en el mundo de las bases relacionales se suele conocer como `left join`, quieres las empresas y en la misma fila y nuevas columna los datos económicos de los paises.  Revisa este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/c%c3%b3mo-resuelvo-operaciones-b%c3%a1sicas-con-datos-al-estilo-sql

Si no alcanza como respuesta te sugiero que agregues un ejemplo de los datos y el codigo de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora y con eso arrancamos. Saludos.