# Cómo puedo comparar dos archivos en R studio teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente:

Tags: r

1. Tengo un archivo Excel denominado claves y cuenta con una columna llave
2. Tengo otro archivo en Excel que tiene la misma columna llave denominado respuestas, más un código de participante y las respuestas del mismo. Hay 40 columnas en cada archivo.
3. Ambos archivos tienen las mismas columnas, están organizados de forma horizontal.
   El archivo de claves cuenta con aproximadamente 120 registros y el archivo de respuestas más de 20.000. El objetivo es que se busque la llave y al coincidir comience a comparar las demás columnas y si son iguales marque 1, de lo contrario 0.
   ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Lo que preguntas es muy sencillo de resolver mediante las operaciones relacionales entre data.frames, revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86730/c%c3%b3mo-resuelvo-operaciones-b%c3%a1sicas-con-datos-al-estilo-sql

Comment: Ahora si quieres una respuesta más concreta te sugiero que armes un [mcve] por que francamente no logro identificar exactamente dónde estaría tu dificultad.